# Transforming responsive web app to a mobile app

Tags: php, html, ios, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I have a simple 5 page website in which users keep track of their water intake. I know nothing about developing mobile apps, been reading the past 5-6 hours about applications like Apache Cordova and Adobe's Phonegap but found out they work only with HTML, CSS and JS.

So what is the best way to transorm my responsive web site (that has PHP, HTML, CSS, JS and is connected to mySQL) to a simple iOS and Android app using Phonegap or Cordova?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently doing exactly the same and was thinking about exactly the same before.

I read a lot of the choice between Cordova and Phonegap (which is a Cordova build), and came to the conclusion that I would use Cordova with the [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) framework in Visual Studio. So far this has provided me a good workspace with a lot of possibilities.

For the second part, transferring data from your webserver towards your app:
I have made several API's which I am running on my webserver and which returns the data in JSON which can be read by Javascript. This data is parsed by my application and shown to the user. For this way you will need a webserver, but even the cheapest shared webhosting should do the job.

The Ionic framework got the basics of making a good multi-platform app, with all the styling already added and a very good [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/).

Comment: +1 For Ionic with server-side web API / web services, I was going to recommend the same thing.  Just a note for OP - Ionic utilizes Angular, so if you are going to use Ionic framework you should familiarize yourself with Angular as well, if you haven't already.

Comment: Angular got some very good documentation, plus it is already out there for a good time, so there are already asked a lot of common questions which got answered. Above that, Angular is actually a pretty good thing to learn because you can use it in normal, non-mobile websites aswell.

Comment: Agreed, Angular is actually my favorite client side MVC/MVVM framework that I've tried so far - it's well documented as you've mentioned, and I didn't find the learning curve to be too steep.  Just wanted to make sure that @TsvetilinBoynovski was aware that it is used in Ionic.

Comment: Huge thanks guys! Will definatelly go learn more about Angular and Ionic!